# How do I dynamically create an array of strings, and at the same time remove white spaces from array entries?

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

Basically, I'd like this part of my code to read from the first line of an input the number of sentences, and then the sentences themselves, and store those in an array (even though the input can contain white spaces, the final array entry may not, not capitals).
For the following input

```
3
one two three
four five six (program didn't let me input another line, but just two more for the sake of the example.)
stack over flow
```

I'd like the following output

```
onetwothree
fourfivesix
stackoverflow
```

The decapitalization is not implemented yet, but I figure that won't be hard.
With my code:

```
void main(){
int length1, length2,i,n;

scanf("%d", &length1);
char *sentenceArray1[length1];
char tempString[100000];
/*The array for storing the first set of sentences, and a temporary string used
for allocating memory in the next loop*/
for(i=0;i<=length1;i++){
        fgets(tempString, 100000, stdin);
        sentenceArray1[i]=malloc((strlen(tempString))*sizeof(char));
        sentenceArray1[i]=tempString;
        for(n=0;n<(strlen(tempString));n++){
                if(tempString[n]==' '){
                        sentenceArray1[i][n]=tempString[n+1];
                        n++;
                }
        printf("%s",sentenceArray1[i]);
        }

}
```

My actual output is as following:

```
one two three
one two three
one two three
onettwo three
onettwo three
onettwo three
onettwotthree
onettwotthree
onettwotthree
onettwotthree
onettwotthree
onettwotthree
```

I am sorry if the markup is way off, this is my first time posting a question.

Comment: You allocate memory with malloc on one line, and then you lose the reference to it on the next line: `sentenceArray1[i]=tempString;`. You end up with all the sentenceArray[i] pointing to tempString. You probably want to `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` tempString instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN (100000)

int main(void)
{
    int numStrings, tempIndex, modIndex, numSpaces;
    char tempString[MAX_STR_LEN];

    printf("Enter number of strings: ");
    scanf("%d", &numStrings);

    while(getchar() != '\n')
        continue;

    char **modifiedStrings = malloc(numStrings * sizeof(*modifiedStrings));

    for(int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter string %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(tempString, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);

        tempIndex = numSpaces = 0;
        while(tempString[tempIndex] != '\n')
        {
            if(tempString[tempIndex++] == ' ')
                numSpaces++;
        }

        modifiedStrings[i] = malloc(strlen(tempString) - numSpaces + 1);

        tempIndex = modIndex = 0;
        while(tempString[tempIndex] != '\n')
        {
            if(tempString[tempIndex] != ' ')
                modifiedStrings[i][modIndex++] = tempString[tempIndex];

            tempIndex++;
        }
        modifiedStrings[i][modIndex] = '\0';
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
        printf("%s\n", modifiedStrings[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Logic**

1. Find out how many strings will be entered.  Store them in a variable (`numStrings`).
2. Remove the newline (`'\n'`) left behind by `scanf`.
3. Create an array of `char *`, one element for each string that will be entered.
4. Get each string.  Store it into a temporary `char` array (`tempString`).
5. Count the number of spaces (`' '`) in the temporary `char` string.
6. `malloc` only enough memory for what you need.
7. Copy every character from the temporary string to the new string (`modifiedStrings[i]`), skipping spaces.
8. Append a `NULL` (`'\0'`) to the end of the new `char` array to make it a string.
9. High-five somebody.

**To Do**

1. Error checking.

**Example Run**

> Enter number of strings: 3
>   Enter string 1: one two three
>   Enter string 2: four five six
>   Enter string 3: stack over flow
>   onetwothree
>   fourfivesix
>   stackoverflow